# Module gym envs not found

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've been trying to get OpenAI's Universe to execute some code all day and not I'm officially stuck. I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6.5.

Whenever I try to excute my .py file, it displays this error.

```
user@comp:~/universe$ python3 ./test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test1.py", line 2, in <module>
import universe
File "/home/user/universe/universe/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from gym.envs.registration import register
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym.envs'
```

I already have gym, universe and docker installed and I'm still having issues.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the output from `pip list`? Or possibly `pip3 list`